# Running script after Cassandra starts (Docker)

Tags: docker, cassandra, bitnami

I'm trying to run a script after Cassandra starts that will create the keyspace.

Here's my docker compose:

```
version: '3.6'

services:
  cassandra:
    container_name: cassandra
    image: bitnami/cassandra:3.11.2
    volumes:
        - ./cassandra_data:/bitnami
        - ./scripts/cassandra_init.sh:/cassandra_init.sh
    environment:
        - CASSANDRA_USER=${CASSANDRA_USERNAME}
        - CASSANDRA_PASSWORD=${CASSANDRA_PASSWORD}
        - CASSANDRA_CLUSTER_NAME=Testing
        - CASSANDRA_PASSWORD_SEEDER=yes
    entrypoint: ["/app-entrypoint.sh"]
    command: ["nami","start","--foreground","cassandra","/cassandra_init.sh"]
volumes:
  cassandra_data:
```

`["nami","start","--foreground","cassandra"]` starts Cassandra. If I start the container without adding my script, it works just fine.

However if I start the container including my script, I get this error after the container starts:
`nami    ERROR Unknown command '/cassandra_init.sh'`

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do with the "nami start" command but it will definitely not work since you don't have an application called nami installed in the container.

Comment: In Kubernetes there is a hook called PostStart where you can execute a command after the container has started. This is the relevant issue reported for Docker compose: https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/1809

Comment: Sorry, I should've been more clear. `["nami","start","--foreground","cassandra"]` is the command that starts Cassandra according to the dockerfile: https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-cassandra/blob/master/3/Dockerfile

If I run `command: ["nami","start","--foreground","cassandra"]` without trying to run my script, it works just fine

Comment: Okay that makes more sense. I just misunderstood then. I'll let someone else answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

In docker.compose I had to call the script `init.sh` and call it:

```
version: '3.6'

services:
  cassandra:
    container_name: cassandra
    image: bitnami/cassandra:3.11.2
    volumes:
        - ./cassandra_data:/bitnami
        - ./scripts/cassandra_init.sh:/init.sh
    environment:
        - CASSANDRA_USER=${CASSANDRA_USERNAME}
        - CASSANDRA_PASSWORD=${CASSANDRA_PASSWORD}
        - CASSANDRA_CLUSTER_NAME=Testing
        - CASSANDRA_PASSWORD_SEEDER=yes
    entrypoint: ["/app-entrypoint.sh"]
    command: ["/init.sh"]
volumes:
  cassandra_data:
```

and the script should look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
nami start cassandra
echo "script stuff here to run after cassandra starts"
```

Comment: @J Del, this is because init.sh is the name of the file called in the entrypoint script. See the entrypoint is copied in here https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-cassandra/blob/master/3/Dockerfile#L10 and then run here https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-cassandra/blob/master/3/Dockerfile#L29, which runs the init.sh here https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-cassandra/blob/master/3/rootfs/app-entrypoint.sh